# Enable trailing comma in vscode

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I am setting eslint in a react typescript project everything works fine except one thing.

I have configured the project in such a way that when I save my file, eslint run and fix all the fixable problems according to the rules I have set. It works.

Eslint consider a missing trailing comma as an error, which is fine for me.

But when I save my project, I can see trailing commas being added, and then removed almost instantly. And as result I can't fix my eslint error.

So I though it would be vscode settings conflicting, so I removed everything from my user settings. It didn't work.

I end up removing all my plugins, uninstalling vscode, removing .vscode in my mac, then reinstalling. I even removed all prettier, eslintrc files from my project

But even in a whole new project, when I save, vscode removes the trailing comma...

If you have any idea of how to change this behaviour I would be glag to hear it :) Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally it seems that I deleted the wrong .vscode.

And the guilty settings is

```
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
       "source.organizeImports": true,
    },
```

Removing it or setting it to false did the trick

Comment: I was having a similar issue.  I had 
```{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.fixAll": true,
  }
}```

changing it to:
```{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.organizeImports",
    "source.fixAll.eslint",
  ]
}```

Did the trick thanks to this github issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/939#issuecomment-609834091

Comment: @JarvisJohnson Your comment would be amazing as an answer!

Comment: PLEASE READ @JarvisJohnson's COMMENT! IT'S THE SOLUTION!

Comment: Cheers @Jakub - have made this an answer now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508443/enable-trailing-comma-in-vscode/74759584#74759584

Answer (score 7):

Moving my reply to an answer as it has solved the issue for a few people -

I previously had multiple `codeActionsOnSave`:

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.fixAll": true
  }
}
```

Moving them to an array fixed the issue:

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": ["source.organizeImports", "source.fixAll.eslint"]
}
```

h/t https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/939#issuecomment-609834091

Comment: Been looking for this for an hour. Here are some other options that you can do on save.

`"editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.formatDocument",
    "source.addMissingImports",
    "source.organizeImports",
    "source.fixAll.eslint"
  ]`

Comment: This worked for me for a while but a recent VS Code update seems to have changed `codeActionsOnSave` to require an object.